# Recursively Search and Update a JSON object

Tags: json, recursion

JSON question for you guys.

Say I have an JSON object like so, with each node being an object with an ID and an array of further nodes:

```
var tree = {
    id: 0,
    items: [{
            id: 48,
            items: [{id: 67, items :[]}]
        }, {
            id: 126,
            items: []
        }]
}
```

Say I wanted to update the object with a new array of items at the appropriate node. So for example, the following would occur using the above tree object:

```
function updateTree(id, array) {
    //code goes here
}
var data = [{id: 121, items :[]}]

tree = UpdateTree(67, data)
```

and tree would come out to equal:

```
tree = {
    id: 0,
    items: [{
            id: 48,
            items: [{id: 67, items : [{id: 121, items :[]}]}]
        }, {
            id: 126,
            items: []
        }]
}
```

how would I implement updateTree here? the recursion is ripping my brain apart. Thanks! Here's a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nus2jyvg/

Comment: @TisteAndii Yes they are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var tree = {
    id: 0,
    items: [{
            id: 48,
            items: [{id: 67, items :[]}]
        }, {
            id: 126,
            items: []
        }]
    }

function updateTree(id, update, tree) {
    if (tree.id === id) {
        tree.items = update
    } else {
        tree.items = tree.items.map(function(item) {
            return updateTree(id, update, item)
        })
    }
    return tree
}
var data = [{id: 121, items :[]}]

tree = updateTree(67, data, tree)
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay so first of in order to make it work recursively, its better to have parameter of same type always. So what I did is encapsulated your main JSON object in an array. Now call `updateTree` on this main array. Now I loop through all objects in a given array, if its `id` matches, we found the element or else, call `updateTree` on current element. So this is depth-first search algorithm. I keep going as deep in the hierarchy as possible, then when you hit a leaf node (one with no items), you go back one level; and evaluate next node on that level. Also I return a boolean to indicate that a match was found so that I can stop traversing immediately and the returned boolean bubbles up. Here's the code.

```
var tree = [{
    id: 0,
    items: [{
            id: 48,
            items: [{id: 67, items :[]}]
        }, {
            id: 126,
            items: []
        }]
}];

function updateTree(tree1,id, arrayArg) {
        var result = false;
    var i=0;
    for(i=0;i<tree1.length;i++){
        if(tree1[i].id == id){
        console.log("match "+tree1[i].id);
        tree1[i].items=arrayArg;
        break;
      }
      else{
        result = updateTree(tree1[i].items,id,arrayArg);
        if(result){break;}
      }
    }
    if(i==tree1.length){result=false;}
    else{result = true;}
    return result;
}
var data = [{id: 121, items :[]}];
var temp = tree; // do a full array copy to preserve original variable, I'm manipulating the main one. Laziness.
var ttree = updateTree(temp,67, data);

console.log(temp);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you for your thorough answer to all of this!

Comment: @austin809 No problem. I enjoyed doing this

Answer (score 1):

You also need to pass the tree to the function if you want it to be recursive. I don't know JScript but in Python:

```
tree = {'id': 0,'items': [{'id': 48,'items': [{'id': 67, 'items' :[]}]}, {'id': 126, 'items': []}]}

data = [{'id': 121, 'items' :[]}]

def UpdateTree(tree, node, data):
    if tree['id'] == node:   # check if its the ID you want
        tree['items'] = data   # update it and return
        return
    for item in tree['items']:   # else go deeper
        UpdateTree(item, node, data)

UpdateTree(tree, 67, data)
```

You can easily replicate this in Javascript. Like this, i think:

```
function UpdateTree(tree, node, data){
    if (tree.id == node){
        tree.items = data;
        return;
    curr_tree_list = tree.items;
    for (var i = 0; i < curr_tree_list.length; i++){
        UpdateTree(curr_tree_list[i], node, data);
    }
}
```